# JHipster Import-jdl Entity generator master.xml and CacheConfiguration not updated

Tags: jhipster, liquibase, changelog, jdl

I generated a microservice application using JHipster then I generated a lot of entities by using the JHipster **"import-jdl"** command.

But recently I noticed that after running **import-jdl** command, newly created changelog files not being reflected on **master.xml** Liquibase file and **CacheConfiguration** class not being updated with a newly created entity.

I think that behaviour happened because JHipster skips the files overriding. But it should ask me before generation if I want to force or skip the file overriding.

Comment: Does not look like a question for stackoverflow

Comment: No, I still did not get the right problem yet. I just guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know the reason for this issue. by mistake, I remove the notes added by JHipster when the application was created

**master.xml**

```
<!-- jhipster-needle-liquibase-add-changelog - JHipster will add liquibase changelogs here -->
<!-- jhipster-needle-liquibase-add-constraints-changelog - JHipster will add liquibase constraints changelogs here -->
```

**CacheConfiguration**

```
// jhipster-needle-ehcache-add-entry
```